# Is there a difference between setting version in gradle.properties and in allProjects?

Tags: gradle

Below I've set the version for all projects

```groovy
allprojects {
    version='1.0.0'
}
```

I'd rather have it in a file `gradle.properties`.
But is it going to apply to all projects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring properties in `gradle.properties` instead of in build scripts is indeed a good practice, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#declare_properties_in_gradle_properties_file

Properties defined in the root project will be inherited to sub-projects, thanks to *properties scopes* as described here https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#N14DEB

> The extra properties and convention properties are inherited from the project's parent, recursively up to the root project. The properties of this scope are read-only.

So yes, you can define version (and other common properties) in `gradle.properties`, these will be applied to all (sub)projects